# Colour cells by value in pyplot.pcolormesh?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualise the QC of a parts  manufacturing process. Two criteria are measured (a & b) and used to calculate a third (c) with this third value used to track the quality of the process. Based on this value the part is either a pass, a fail, or sent for rework. What I'd like to do is plot the data for a batch of parts against an underlying heatmap showing these pass/fail/rework boundaries.

This image below  shows the boundaries plotted on a pcolormap. Ideally I'd like the five sections to be coloured from left-to-right as red, amber, green, amber, red. These correspond to values <20, 21-30, 31-50, 51-70, >71.

[pcolormap criteria boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t76k4.png)

I've tried to create a 5-colour cmap to overlay on this - it's along the right lines but the colours don't map correctly. Presumably because the cmap is scaling to the underlying values rather than to the fixed boundaries needed. Playing around with Vmin/Vmax tightens things up but it's still not quite right.

```
colours = ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'orange', 'red']
cmap = ListedColormap(colours)
plt.pcolormesh(a, b, c, cmap = cmap, shading = 'auto', vmin = 20, vmax = 70)
plt.pcolormesh(a, b, boundaries, cmap='binary', shading = 'auto', alpha = 0.5)
plt.show
```

[overlay cmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoyhI.png)

Is there a way to colour the cells depending on their value, or generating a cmap that doesn't scale to the data?

Comment: I think what you want is a BoundaryNorm https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html

Comment: Thanks. Adding norm = BoundaryNorm((0, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100), ncolors=num_colours, clip=False) seemed to sort it out.